# How can I pass extra flags to FZF/ripgrep commands with the leader key?

Tags: normal-mode, filesystem, multiple-files, find, plugin-fzf

## Current functionality

When I use `<C-P>` and `<C-Å>` I can respectively search file names and contents. Everything works great.

## Target functionality

When prepending either with `<leader>`, I would like to pass the `--no-ignore` flag to each command (ex. `<legend><C-P>`).

### Here are the relevant parts of my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <C-P> :Files<CR>
nnoremap <C-Å> :Find<CR>

Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '~/.fzf', 'do': './install --all' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' " Fuzzy search

let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'rg --files --hidden --follow --glob "!{.git,node_modules}/*"' " Enable respecting .gitignore for files
command! -bang -nargs=* Find call fzf#vim#grep('rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --hidden --follow --glob "!{.git,node_modules}/*" --color "always" '.shellescape(<q-args>), 1,
\ <bang>0 ? fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, 'up:60%')
\         : fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, 'right:50%:hidden', '?'),
\ <bang>0)
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
```

Comment: This site is not about others doing the work for you. Tell us what have you tried;  where are you struggling?

Answer (score 3):

Please note that I changed your mapping to suit my keyboard. However this is what I got in terms of functionality:

```
nnoremap <C-P> :MyFind0<CR>
nnoremap <Leader><C-P> :MyFind1<CR>
command! -bang -nargs=* MyFind0 call MyFind(0, <q-args>, <bang>0)
command! -bang -nargs=* MyFind1 call MyFind(1, <q-args>, <bang>0)
function! MyFind(numArg, qArg, bangArg)
  let cmd='rg --column --line-number --no-heading --fixed-strings --ignore-case --hidden --follow --glob "!{.git,node_modules}/*" --color "always" '
  if a:numArg == 1
    let cmd.='--no-ignore '
  endif
call fzf#vim#grep(cmd.shellescape(a:qArg), 1,
\ a:bangArg ? fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, 'up:60%')
\         : fzf#vim#with_preview({'options': '--delimiter : --nth 4..'}, 'right:50%:hidden', '?'),
\ a:bangArg)
endfunction
```

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow, thank you for giving it a go!

Comment: @b00t So, did it work for you?